# Extract a substring from a string based on the position of character - Python

Tags: python, string, substring

Im trying to extract the substrings from the below string

```
   package: name='com.example.tracker' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0'
```

as string 1 : versionCode='1'
and as string 2: versionName='1.0'

I used str.find('versionCode) which returns me the index of 'v' in the versioncode and i used string length to access '1'. However there are time the versioncode might be a double digit number so I can't fix the location of the digit. Is there a way to achieve this?

If the string is

```
    package: name='com.example.tracker' versionCode='12' versionName='12.0'
```

I need to extract 12 and 12.0. 
My implementation can support single digits but the digits will vary.

```
 if line.find('versionCode') != -1:
            x = line.find('versionCode') 
            versionCode = line[x+13:x+15]
```

Comment: Use regular expressions to do this, or write a real parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to do this.

In each of the below lines we use the pattern `(.*?)` to perform a non-greedy search within the quotes to extract the string, and then pull `group(1)` rather than `group(0)` on the returned object, as `0` returns the full match across the whole input string, and `1` gives the first regex capture group.

```
import re

packageDetails = "package: name='com.example.tracker' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0'"
name = re.search("name='(.*?)'", packageDetails).group(1)
versionCode = re.search("versionCode='(.*?)'", packageDetails).group(1)
versionName = re.search("versionName='(.*?)'", packageDetails).group(1)

print "package name is :", name
print "version code is :", versionCode
print "version name is :", versionName
```

And this outputs:

```
package name is : com.example.tracker
version code is : 1
version name is : 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate the string with built-in methods to get the values you need:

```
packageDetails = "package: name='com.example.tracker' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0'"
details = packageDetails
params = ['name=', 'versionCode=', 'versionName=']
params.reverse()
values = []
for p in params:
    details, v = details.split(p)
    values.append(v.strip().strip("'"))
values.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could build a dictionary:

```
>>> details = { x.split('=')[0] : x.split('=')[1].strip("'") for x in a.split()[1:] }
>>> details
{
  "name" : "com.example.tracker",
  "versionCode" : "1",
  "versionName" : "1.0"
}
>>> details['name']
"com.example.tracker"
>>> details['versionCode'] == '1'
true
```

Or if you don't care about stripping the "'"s

```
>>> dict(x.split('=') for x in a.split()[1:])
{
  "name" : "'com.example.tracker'",
  "versionCode" : "'1'",
  "versionName" : "'1.0'"
}
```